# Passing the parent pointer in Qt | ERROR: no member named in QObject

Tags: c++, qt

I am new to qt and I am trying to create a program where the MainWindow calls a QDialog to enter some data.
  The problem is that the parent() at my QDialog does not have any access to the public methods of the MainWindow in our case the

```
void save_city(const City *city); //public method of MainWindow
```

The code is actually big so here is some of the code.Thanks.

mainwindow.h

```
#include <QGraphicsScene>
#include <QGraphicsView>
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QTextStream>
#include <QVector>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QFile>
#include "dialog_add_city.h"
#include "street.h"
#include "city.h"
#include "map.h"

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    //main Window constructor
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    //main Window deconstructor
    ~MainWindow();
    /*utility function to save the city
     *the function is public so that also QDialogs 
     *data saves can */
   //////////////
   //here is the public function
    void save_city(const City *city);


private slots:


private:
    Map mainMap;
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    QGraphicsView view;
    QGraphicsScene scene;
};
```

dialog_add_city.h

```
#ifndef DIALOG_ADD_CITY_H
#define DIALOG_ADD_CITY_H

#include <QDialog>
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "City.h"

namespace Ui {
class Dialog_Add_City;
}

class Dialog_Add_City : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit Dialog_Add_City(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~Dialog_Add_City();

private slots:
    //Add New City Button clicked-Adds an new city to our city_locations.txt
    void on_PushButton_Add_New_City_clicked();

private:
    Ui::Dialog_Add_City *ui;
};

#endif // DIALOG_ADD_CITY_H
```

dialog_add_city.cpp

```
#include "dialog_add_city.h"
#include "ui_dialog_add_city.h"

Dialog_Add_City::Dialog_Add_City(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Dialog_Add_City)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

Dialog_Add_City::~Dialog_Add_City()
{
    delete ui;
}

void Dialog_Add_City::on_PushButton_Add_New_City_clicked()
{
    City *city=new City(ui->lineEdit_cityName->text(),
                        ui->lineEdit_X_Ko->text().toDouble(),
                        ui->lineEdit_Y_Ko->text().toDouble());
    qDebug() << ui->lineEdit_cityName->text()
             << ui->lineEdit_X_Ko->text()
             << ui->lineEdit_Y_Ko->text();
 /////////////////////////////
 //HERE IS THE PROBLEM   
 parent()->save_city(city);        
}
```

Any other suggestions are welcomed!

Comment: ***The problem is that the parent() at my QDialog does not have any access to the public methods of the MainWindow*** I say the dialog should not have to access MainWindow directly. One way around this is to emit a signal in the dialog connected to a slot in the MainWindow.

Comment: Your problem is parent() is a pointer to a `QWidget`. You can use `myMainWindow* pMainWindow = qobject_cast<MainWindow*>(parent());` to fix that. However I still stand by my first remark.

Answer (score 0):

The Problem is that `parent()` will return a pointer the parent object as QObject.

[QObject Documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qobject.html#parent)

As dreschrjm pointed out you could try to cast the object via

```
MyWidget *myWidget = qobject_cast<MyWidget *>(obj);
```

[from The Meta-Object System](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/metaobjects.html)

Answer (score 0):

Suggestion: Use Qt's signal/slot mechanism to avoid a backward reference to the parent.

Declare `save_city` as signal in `Dialog_Add_City`.
Declare `save_city` in `MainWindow` as slot

Connect both where the dialog is created:
e.g.

```
void MainWindow::show_add_city_dialog()
{
  Dialog_Add_city dialog;

  connect(&dialog, &Dialog_Add_city::save_city, this, &MainWindow::save_city);
  dialog.exec();
}
```

Replace `parent()->save_city(city);` in `Dialog_Add_City` with `emit save_city(city);`

Ensure that the new city object doesn't leak, I think a better design would be to create the City object elsewhere not in the dialog.

so

```
emit save_city(ui->lineEdit_cityName->text(), 
  ui->lineEdit_X_Ko->text().toDouble(), 
  ui->lineEdit_Y_Ko->text().toDouble());
```

and the slot

```
void MainWindow::save_city(const QString &cityName, double x, double y)
{
  City *city=new City(cityName, x, y);
  // do some interresting things with city.
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you reply it was very helpful but the line                   connect(dialog, &Dialog_Add_city::save_city, this, &MainWindow::save_city);  should be corrected as connect(&dialog, &Dialog_Add_city::save_city, this, &MainWindow::save_city);